# javascript global variable within functions

Tags: javascript

i have a global variable and functions:

```
var filesUploader = [];
function updateFiles() {
          filesUploader[0] = document.getElementById("currentfiles").files;
}

function second() {
          alert(filesUploader[0].length);
}
```

But the function second gives value 0 even if files in function updateFiles() are loaded to variable. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Show us where you are calling `updateFiles` and `second`. If you do it in the right places in the right order, the code will work.

Comment: Please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: updateFiles() is called <input type="file" id="currentfiles" onclick="updateFiles()" /> and second is called when I click on a button after files are loaded

Comment: @evelyn The _click_ event is probably fired and resolved before a file has finished being selected. Consider using the _change_ event